# Problem with Reshape in multires modifier

Tags: multiresolution

Hi I am trying to reshape my mesh with multires modifier from a sclupted mesh. Both have equal number of verts. But Reshape glitches. Am I doing anything wrong?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Similar to shape keys the vertex indices must match for both models. The models must have the same number of vertices and the order must be the same. To overcome this limitation try a *Multires* modifier + a *Shrinkwrap* modifier. Use *Project* and *Positive* + *Negative* direction for the *Shrinkwrap* modifier.